# What is the touchable trigger distance for iOS7's back gesture?

Tags: ios, guidelines, gestures, swipe

One of the screens in my app has progress slider with draggable handle. Currently this conflicts with the iOS 7 back navigation swipe gesture from left edge of the screen. You can't select the handle when it's at the start because the OS wants to go back instead.

I want to keep the back gesture and move the slider further in from the edge of the screen.

**So I simply want to know how wide is the touchable/trigger area for this iOS 7 gesture in points?**

I can use trial and error until it stops conflicting or dump the slider way further in, but it would be useful of know what portion of the screen is detecting a swipe to go back. I couldn't find anything in Apple's docs.

Comment: I'd go for trial an error, I think it's going to be the most accurate way if you are thorough on your tests. Even more, after the tests, you could write a post with that information, here or in a specialized blog. It will be helpful for more people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any documentation on this either.

What might be useful is the standard "aqua space" for auto-layout constraints. This is a constraint standard used in the app sdk which hopefully is considered when this feature was developed.

Generally speaking I'd used at least this much space between the edge and view within it. This includes UI controls such as progress bars.

Refer to the response to an SO question about the standard aqua space:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055900/what-constant-can-i-use-for-the-default-aqua-space-in-autolayout

Comment: It was hard to do trial and error on this due to the imprecise nature of a touch and exactly where on the screen your finger is touching.

However, using the Aqua space seems to result in very high level of successful drag actions and hardly any false positives.

We will continue this testing and feedback with more users before a final decision, but initial testing the Aqua space seems enough to avoid the back gesture being triggered